# Need help in stored procedure for calendar days

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am stuck in stored procedure where I need some help. I have a procedure in which it tells me how many month or week or day it has been within two dates but I don't know how it is calculating the day difference between two days as difference between '2015-06-01' and '2015-06-30' for this it shows it is whole month or entry is 1 month but for '2015-06-01' and '2015-07-01' it shows 1 month and 2 days. Also it calculates the remaining days by divinding them to 7 for weeks but I want calendar weeks. I am not able to do both the things.

This is the code-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetDateParts 
(
@StartDate DATE ,
@EndDate DATE
)
AS
BEGIN

    /* variables to be used */
    DECLARE @Return VARCHAR(5)
    /*  
        Get the difference between the two dates
        add 1 to the value to include the first day in the count
    */
    , @TotalNumberOfDays INT
    , @DaysInMonth TINYINT;

    /*  table variable to store the number of days in a month
        this would be better as a fixed SQL table as it'll 
        be called a lot */
    DECLARE @Months TABLE 
        ([Month] TINYINT, [NoDays] TINYINT);

    /* month values */
    INSERT INTO @Months
    VALUES
        (1, 31),
        (2, 28),
        (3, 31),
        (4, 30),
        (5, 31),
        (6, 30),
        (7, 31),
        (8, 31),
        (9, 30),
        (10, 31),
        (11, 30),
        (12, 31);

    /* Create Result table */
    DECLARE @ResultTable TABLE ([MonthNumber] TINYINT, [FullMonth] BIT, [Weeks] TINYINT, [Days] TINYINT)

    -- set the count as the mointh number
    DECLARE @Count TINYINT = MONTH(@StartDate);
    SET @TotalNumberOfDays = DATEDIFF(day, @StartDate, @EndDate)+1
    WHILE @Count <= MONTH(@EndDate)
    BEGIN

        /* get the number of days in the month */
        SELECT @DaysInMonth = [NoDays] FROM @Months WHERE [Month] = @Count;

        /* 
        Check if it's a leap year and alter the number of days in Febuary to 29 
        This was taken from https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1527/sql-server-function-to-determine-a-leap-year/
        */
        IF((SELECT CASE DATEPART(mm, DATEADD(dd, 1, CAST((CAST(@StartDate AS VARCHAR(4)) + '0228') AS DATE))) 
                WHEN 2 THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
                END) = 1) AND MONTH(@StartDate) = 2
            SET @DaysInMonth = 29;

        IF (@TotalNumberOfDays >= @DaysInMonth)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @ResultTable ([MonthNumber], [FullMonth])
            VALUES (@Count, 1)

            SET @TotalNumberOfDays = @TotalNumberOfDays - (@DaysInMonth-DAY(@StartDate));

            SET @StartDate = DATEADD(day, (@DaysInMonth-DAY(@StartDate)+1), @StartDate);

            SET @Count = @Count + 1;
        END
        ELSE IF (@TotalNumberOfDays >= 7)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @ResultTable ([MonthNumber], [Weeks])
            VALUES (@Count, CAST(@TotalNumberOfDays/7 AS INT))
            DECLARE @Remainder TINYINT = @TotalNumberOfDays%7;

            IF (@Remainder = 0)
            BEGIN
                SET @Count = @Count + 1;
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @TotalNumberOfDays = @Remainder;
            END
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @ResultTable ([MonthNumber], [Days])
            VALUES (@Count, @TotalNumberOfDays)
            SET @Count = @Count + 1;
        END

    END;

    -- Return Results
    SELECT * FROM @ResultTable;
END
```

Can anyone help as it is important to me. Thnaks in advance

Comment: May be just use function `datediff(wk, @start, @end)`, `datediff(dd, @start, @end)`?

Comment: I can't really use that beacuse it shows a week difference even if there a date difference of 4 days. I want to show only week when there is difference of 7 days and there is complete whole week as I have data week wise to represent not in break up days

Comment: then use `datediff(dd, @start, @end) / 7` for weeks.

Comment: I have tried it for ex- see this select datediff('2015-07-07','2015-07-16')/7 it shows 1 but in if we look at the calendar there is no full week here

Answer (score 0):

Looking to you code there is need of Nested loop where Outer While Loop is for Month (which will iterate through months between Start and End Date) and Inner WHILE Loop will iterate through Number of Weeks in the Month which will also checks the Week is full and first day is Week Start Date. let's say Date of Monday. If this condition is not satisfied, then fill the table as DayWise Entry.

Comment your text for any query further.

Comment: yeah that is what I want ...can you help me through it?